# The multi-part identifier "i.charged_amount" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger where if a client tries to purchase something, but if they pass their credit card limit, the transaction is cancelled.

my tables are:
customers(name,ssn,**code**),
accounts(customer_code,**acc_number**,balance,rate),
creditcard(issued,expired,limit,balance,**cc_number**),
transactions(date,cc_number,charged_amount,**conf_numb**er,shop_code)

And what I wrote is

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_balance ON transactions
FOR INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @balance int, @limit int

    SELECT @balance = balance, @limit = limit
    FROM creditcard
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON creditcard.cc_number = i.cc_number

    IF (@balance + i.charged_amount > @limit)
    BEGIN        
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
```

But I get a

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure check_balance, Line 10
> The multi-part identifier "i.charged_amount" could not be bound.
> where line 10 is
> IF (@balance + i.charged_amount >
> @limit)

I know that the message means that I can't use i.* , cause the scope of it is only in the `select..from`.

I tried using referencing new row as I, but I got a syntax error near referencing. I am using SQL Server 2005.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
create trigger check_balance on transactions

for insert
as

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM creditcard 
               INNER JOIN inserted i ON creditcard.cc_number = i.cc_number 
           GROUP BY c.cc_number
           HAVING MIN(creditcard.balance)+SUM(i.charged_amount)>MIN(creditcard.limit)
          )
BEGIN
    raiserror ('bad limit found',16,1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    return
END
```

Comment: This would still allow through multiple different purchases on the same card that collectively exceed the account limit.

Comment: @Martin, good catch, you get an "A" on the homework for today!

Answer (score 5):

Your assignment to scalar variables won't work with multi row inserts. `inserted` is a table that may contain any number of rows.

An `insert` may even contain multiple different rows for the same credit card that individually are OK but collectively would exceed the account limit.

The logic would need to be something like...

```
IF EXISTS
(
SELECT c.cc_number
FROM creditcard c
INNER JOIN inserted i ON c.cc_number = i.cc_number
GROUP BY c.cc_number, c.limit, c.balance
HAVING c.balance + SUM(i.charged_amount) > c.limit
)

ROLLBACK...
```

Comment: +1, good catch with the multiple transactions issue!  you could run a small transaction 1,000 times to get by the limit without that check: `;WITH AllNumbers AS (SELECT 1 AS Number UNION ALL SELECT Number+1 FROM AllNumbers WHERE Number<1000) INSERT INTO transactions (date,cc_number,charged_amount,conf_number,shop_code) SELECT GETDATE(),'12345',100,1234,'X' FROM AllNumbers OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)`

Answer (score -4):

I think the problem is that you are trying to use the alias i when it is only in scope for the query you aliased it in. Kindly change the reference in the IF statement to inserted instead of i.

Comment: Need a lot more than that, sorry

Comment: And changing IF (@balance + i.charged_amount > @limit) 
 to IF (@balance + inserted.charged_amount > @limit) is wrong how? I'm not sure why I have been downvoted.